# A simple binomial distribution problem why is my textbook saying I am getting the answer wrong.

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello everybody I am doing some homework problems in preparation for my upcoming exam. The name of the course is Statistics for Engineers. Anyhow here is the problem description:

Let $X$ denote a random variable having a binomial distribution with $p = 0.2$ and $n = 4$. Find $P(X=2)$.

Anyhow I used this formula: $p(x)=\dbinom{n}{x}(p)^x (1-p)^{n-x}$

By simply plugging in the values I came up with: 0.1536. But the answer at the end of the book says 0.5136. Did I do something wrong? I doubt the book is wrong. Did I misunderstood the problem? Any suggestions are welcome. Remember this homework, well not turn in homework but treat it as homework anyhow.

P.S. Anybody notice the two real numbers are anagrams.

Comment: I think your book's editors simply missed that the digits got swapped.  The answer is what you got.  (Think of it this way:  You have a coin balanced heavily towards tails.  Is there really a better-than-half chance that you'll get two heads and two tails?)

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: I will probably ask the professor just to confirm that I am right. You might be right as I did read bad reviews of this textbook having some wrong answers.

Comment: It's indeed wrong: $$p(2)={4\choose 2}(1/5)^2(4/5)^2=6\cdot{16\over625}={96\over625}<1/2<0.5136.$$ (Your answer is right.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} = \frac{4!}{2!^2} = 6 \\
0.2^2 = 0.04, \\
0.8^2 = .64,\\
\\
6\cdot 0.04 \cdot 0.64 = 0.1536.
$$

You're fine. Furthermore note that the value is $0.1536$ exactly, and that value is not rounded off.

---

More intuitively, assume that the value was $0.5136$. That would mean that a single value in the discrete binomial distribution is more likely than all other values combined. Does that make sense for that parameterization?